# How to increase the row hight in ListView in Vtiger 5.4

Tags: php, vtiger

Am new here and said that. I would appreciate any and all the help thats possible which will help me understand how I can make the best out of StackOVerflow. I do have a lot of questions though as I am into freelance programming/designing works.

So the first question that I have is How to increase the row hight in ListView in Vtiger 5.4?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the row height in ListView by updating the style.css of yor current theme that is located at

http://www.yoursite.com/themes/your-current-theme/style.css

You have to add height property to two class named "lvtColData" and "lvtColDataHover", I shown a demo in firebug, please see snapshot below.

[image: snapshot]
[see full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAUsL.png)